# Python Functions Instead of Python Scripts

Tags: python, cron, schedule

Is it possible to have the below code run a python function instead of a python script?

```
from crontab import CronTab
from datetime import datetime

cron = CronTab(user='username')
job = cron.new(command='python example1.py')
job.minute.every(1)

cron.write()
```

I have tried this but it clearly doesn't work

```
from crontab import CronTab

def(trial):
     myFile = open('append.txt', 'a') 
     myFile.write('\nAccessed on ' + str(datetime.now()))


cron = CronTab(user='username')
job = cron.new(command='trial')
job.minute.every(1)

cron.write()
```

Comment: For the future, please: 1) Link to the library you are using, since apparently there are multiple libraries with that name (and the first one I found does not expose the API you are using); 2) Make sure code you post is syntactically valid. `def(trial)` isn't, you probably meant `def trial()`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your library manages the crontab provided by a cron daemon on your system (you can verify this using `crontab -l` on a shell - it should show the cronjob you created when calling `cron.write()`).

This means that it can only run things you could otherwise run on a shell. So there is no way to run a python function unless you have a python file containing it (like in your first example).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. I'm sorry I can't upvote your answer because I apparently don;t have enough reputation?

Comment: No problem - you should be able to accept the answer though (iirc. only after a few minutes).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `-c` flag to specify the command that you want to run
example:

```py
cron = CronTab(user='username')
job = cron.new(command='python -c "print(\"Hello World\")"')
job.minute.every(1)
```

Comment: Please don't do that, it's going to be **extremely** ugly for all but the smallest scripts